# Custom list view add text view to new line of row

Tags: android, listview

I Create this list view

[image]

With this code

Xml Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
   >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/lblDate"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
         android:id="@+id/lblDescription"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        />
   
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
         android:id="@+id/lblAmount"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
         android:id="@+id/lblPrice"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code

```
public class FillList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    
    List<Map<String, String>> prolist = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {

        String[] from = {"D", "C", "B","A"};
        int[] views = { R.id.lblPrice,R.id.lblAmount,R.id.lblDescription,R.id.lblDate};
        final SimpleAdapter ADA = new SimpleAdapter(Products.this,
                prolist, R.layout.lsttemplate, from,
                views);
        lstSoratHesab.setAdapter(ADA);
        
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

          Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();

          datanum.put("D", "price");
          datanum.put("C", "amount");
          datanum.put("B", "description");
          datanum.put("A", "date");
          prolist.add(datanum);
          
          while (rs.next()) {
              datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();

              
              datanum.put("D", rs.getString("Bes"));
              datanum.put("C", rs.getString("Bed"));
              datanum.put("B", rs.getString("Sharh"));
              datanum.put("A", rs.getString("Date"));
              prolist.add(datanum);

          }
    }               
}

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFE56.png
```

Because description is too long i want change list view to

[image]

Question:How can change listview and set description in new line in list view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this layout is to use two LinearLayouts in your design. The parent LinearLayout should have a vertical orientation and the child LinearLayout should have a horizontal orientation. You can see this in the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:width="match_parent"
        android:height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <!-- Most of your TextViews go there -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The description TextView -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lblDescription" />

</LinearLayout>
```